Movie about kids who don't get along a first, scenes at a carnival and in the woods
Last time I saw this I was 7 years old! It is a family comedy, probably of the 90s. 
It's about a little boy who moved to a new place I think, and a girl (I think she's blonde) that is really annoying and they hate each other. In one scene they wouldn't let him into a carnival ride because he was too short, but she wore heels (I think) and they let her, then she vomited all over the other kids. 
There was another boy (who was fat, I think) that was bullying him, and at some point the two boys were in the woods and the bully threw him down, got on top of him and then put one worm in each nostril of his. But at the end the bully turned out to be good, and the girl and him became friends and I think his dad and her mom became a couple...? 
Do you know which movie I am talking about?

Welcome to Movies & TV!   What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold. You might also want to change the title of your question to something more descriptive.

I recognize everything except the worm part.

Problem Child 2. 1991. Junior is a problem child who moves to new town/school and meets girl called Trixie who is worse than him. Her mom is school nurse played by Amy Yasbeck who ends up with Juniors dad Ben (played by John Ritter) in end. Theres a scene where Junior sabotages controls of carnival ride with Trixie on board (after she uses platform shoes to be tall enough to ride). This causes everyone on ride and carnival to projectile vomit. The fat bully is named Murph and they become friends in the end. There's also a dinner table scene with salad full of cockroaches.
